# Coordinate independence of the matrix representation of the „Minkowski Metrik“.

Tags: physics, bilinear-form

In physics we learn that we can equip $\mathbb{R}^4$ with a bilinear form: $(\cdot,\cdot): \mathbb{R}^4 \times \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, that we call the „Minkowski Metric“. With respect to the standart basis it is given by: $(x,y):= x_0y_0-x_1y_1-x_2y_2-x_3y_3$.

The „matrix representation“ of this bilinear form **with respect to the standart basis** is:

$$
\eta:=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&0\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&0&0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then $(x,y)=x^T \eta y$. My problem now is that I‘ve never seen a proof that this matrix representation doesn’t change if we perform a change of basis to the coordinate system of another „inertial observer“. This would of course follow easily if we knew that such change of basis are carried out by linear transformations from the Lorentz-Group, which by definition are invariant with respect to the „Minkowski Metrik“. So is there more to this or must I just accept that „inertial reference frames“ are just defined to be exactly these bases that just don’t happen to change the matrix representation above?

Comment: Of course this matrix representation will change if we make an arbitrary linear base-change.

Comment: Yes of course, I‘m just so confused by the fact that my physics textbook often states: „since the form is coordinate invariant it follows that…“ which I suppose is true in the context of physics where we only consider inertial observers, but I think that it is a stupid thing to say, because they basically mean: „since the form is coordinate invariant with respect to all coordinate systems that it is invariant with it follows that…“. Do I see that correctly or is there more to that? (But I suppose physics.stackexchange would be a better place for this, so I‘ll probably delete my question)

Comment: "The form is coordinate invariant" - That means its value on a pair of vectors is invariant, not that the components of the matrix are invariant. The components of the vectors and the matrix may both change, but the product remains the same: $x^T\eta y=x'^T\eta' y'$.

Comment: Ok but isn’t every well defined form coordinate invariant under this definition?

Comment: I suppose so. But the Minkowski metric is special because of its physical meaning. Indeed physics.SE might be a better place for you to get further clarification.

Comment: A quick search gives https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/230495/lorentz-invariance-of-the-minkowski-metric

Comment: @HenryT.  suggest you work out the precise matrices in the Lorentz group, or at least look it up. The definition  tends to discard  matrices, if  $A^T \eta A \neq \eta $ then we discard $A.$ The opposite procedure is to build up,    for example $$
A:=\begin{pmatrix}
\cosh \theta &\sinh \theta&0&0\\
\sinh \theta&\cosh \theta&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}
$$